# Assigning the key of the object as a value inside that object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, lodash

In lodash we have the _mapKeys method that I'm using like this:

Here is an array of objects:

```
const posts = [
  {
    id: 123,
    title: 'Hello',
  },
  {
    id: 321,
    title: 'World',
  },
];
```

From there I use the method like so:

```
const postsObjWithKeys = _.mapKeys(posts, 'id');

console.log(postsObjWithKeys);
```

And the result is:

```
{
  123: {id: 123, title: 'Hello'},
  321: {id: 321, title: 'World'}
}
```

Perfect! Exactly what I want!

**The question is how would I achieve this in 'reverse'? Meaning if I had an object like this:**

```
const posts = {
  123: {
    title: 'Hello' 
  },
  321: {
    title: 'World'
  }
}
```

Is it possible to take the key and assign it as a value if id? The end result being:

```
const posts = {
  123: {
    id: 123,
    title: 'Hello' 
  },
  321: {
    id: 321,
    title: 'World'
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With lodash you can achieve the reverse using [`_.mapValues()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#mapValues):

```js
const posts = {
  123: {
    title: 'Hello' 
  },
  321: {
    title: 'World'
  }
}

const result = _.mapValues(posts, (value, id) => _.assign({}, value, { id }));

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: How the hell did that not occur to me? I need some sleep. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Just iterate all the keys and add them as `id` on the Object:

```js
const posts = {
  123: {
    title: 'Hello' 
  },
  321: {
    title: 'World'
  }
}

Object.keys(posts).forEach(k=>{
    posts[k].id = k;
});

console.log(posts);

/*
const posts = {
  123: {
    id: 123,
    title: 'Hello' 
  },
  321: {
    id: 321,
    title: 'World'
  }
}
*/
```

Comment: simpler than library methods